# Django Models: Filter a subset of a query set

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have these two models:

```
class InspectionPoint(models.Model):
    ...
    review_check = models.BooleanField(default = 0)
    flight = models.ForeignKey(
            Flight, 
            related_name='inspection_points',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            null=True, blank=True
            )
    ...

class ImageSnapshot(models.Model):
    ...
    inspection = models.ForeignKey(
        InspectionPoint, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name = 'snapshots'
    )
    flight = models.ForeignKey(
            Flight, 
            related_name='snapshots',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            null=True, blank=True
            )
    ...
```

I already have snapshots queryset with:
`snapshots = ImageSnapshots.objects.filter(flight=flight)`
but that gives me all snapshots.

I want to filter snapshots that have only (review_check = True)

Any idea?

Comment: `ImageSnapshots.objects.filter(flight=flight, inspection__review_check=True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ImageSnapshot.objects.filter(flight=flight, inspection__review_check=True)
```